# how to download html web pages using C#

Tags: c#

I need to download a number of web pages
 with a pattern like

```
../directory/page_1.html
../directory/page_2.html 
...
../directory/page_80.html
```

and save them into a folder can i do this simple task using c# ?, please help. any suggestions

```
for(i=1;i<81;i++){
string url = "http://mywebsite.com/cats/page_" + convert.tostring(i)
+ ".html"
//
// code to download the html page 
//
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new WebClient ().DownloadFile("http://abc.html", @"C:\downloadedFile_abc.html");

// Or you can get the file content without saving it
string htmlCode = new WebClient ().DownloadString("http://abc.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=1;i<81;i++){
string url = "http://mywebsite.com/cats/page_" + convert.tostring(i)
+ ".html"
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
    //you can download as a html file 
    client.DownloadFile(url, @"C:\" + i.ToString() + ".html");

    // Or you can get html source code as a string
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
}
}
```

And if you want to get some data from html code(such as table that has "xx" className) you can use [HTMLAGILITYPACK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore/)